# BUX changes and Issue with Dream job

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

If you place a person into a dream job, you should get a Bux. But when placing new residents into their dream job, it does not give me any Bux.

At least starting with the lastest update, I have been having this issue (I believe the Mar 17 update, v. 1.4.1).

If I have an empty slot, I do get a BUX
If there is an existing person, at times I get BUX and recently not at all.

I fill the floors with Level 9 with matching "dream job" residents to the non-resident floor. At times, I will get a level 4 swap with level 9 and I get a BUX but most of the time it won't. Even if I swap a level 9 with another level 9, no BUX

After emailing Disney Support, I got some responses:

> I'd be happy to explain!
>
> 1 Bux will be awarded for the first Dream Job given to a Bitizen on a
>   particular floor. After that, you'll only be awarded 1 Bux for giving
>   a Bitzen their Dream Job on that same floor if their skill level is 9.
>   This new system was implemented in the last update.
>
> I hope you continue to have a great time playing Tiny Death Star!
>   Please feel free to write to us again if you have any other questions
>   or comments.
>
> Kendre Star Wars: Tiny Death Star Support"
>
> "Hi again!
>
> Is it the first level 9 Bitizen on that floor to have a dream job? The
>   way the new dream job system works is a little tricky, but if you're
>   moving Bitizens from floor to floor to floor, you might not get the
>   Bux you're supposed to.
>
> The first Bitizen on that floor to work their dream job will award you
>   one Bux. If the next Bitizen to work their dream job on that floor is
>   a higher level than the first one, you'll get another Bux. But if
>   they're lower than the first one, you will not get any Bux.
>
> I encourage you to keep trying! If the problems keeps happening to
>   multiple Bitizens on multiple floors, you may want to try syncing to
>   Facebook or restarting your device.
>
> Please feel free to write to us again if you have any other questions
>   or comments. We're always happy to help!
>
> Kendre Star Wars: Tiny Death Star Support

---

> If there is already a level 9 Bitizen working their dream job on that
>   floor, then no, I don't believe you'll get another Bux for hiring
>   another level 9 Bitizen for their dream job on that same floor. The
>   only time you'll get a second Bux for hiring a Bitizen for their dream
>   job is if they're higher level than the first one (9 is the highest,
>   but both 8 and 9 are considered "high levels").
>
> This new system was put into place to stop players from achieving an
>   unfair amount of Bux by simply swapping out Bitizens over and over
>   again, because that's not how the game is supposed to be played.
>
> Take care,
>
> Kendre Star Wars: Tiny Death Star Support

The question I have is: Could anyone validate this point because that does not seem to work for me... Either case, any replies are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to post the exact same question and found this!

Anyway, my observation is this: Say you have a shop with 3 level 9 dream jobbers, you will NOT get any bux by making one of these level 9 dream jobbers jobless, and replacing with another dream jobber because level 9 is already the highest.

However, you can get a bux if you have TWO or more extra dream jobbers for the same shop. For easy explaining, let's call the 3 original level 9 dream jobbers A, B and C. And you have another 2, X and Y, with skill level 4 and 7 respectively. Suppose you free up a slot by making anyone of A,B or C jobless and swap in either X or Y.

You will never get any bux from swapping in X or Y because both their skills are lower than 9. But the KEY point here is the sequence in which you swap them in.

Sequence 1: If you swap in X (4) first, of course you won't get any bux. But after you evict X and swap in Y (7), you WILL get bux for Y because Y's skill is higher than X's. Of course, you won't get any bux from swapping back the original level 9 dream jobber.

Sequence 2: Swap Y in first - you won't get any bux. And you also won't get any bux when you evict Y and swap X in because X's skill is lower than Y's.

In the same logic, if your shop only has 1 or 2 workers originally, you will get bux from the bitizen who fills up the vacancies at the shop. But once you get a level 9 in, you'll have to use the above method.

I read somewhere that you could intentionally leave a shop empty for a while, and then to swap in the extra dream jobbers to get bux (while your level 9 dream jobbers are hiding elsewhere) but I'm not sure if this method does work. Anyone who has successfully gotten bux this way (in this paragraph) please do let us know.

Answer (score 0):

There are instances where you can replace a level 9 bitizen with another level 9 bitizen and still receive a bonus bux.

I've tracked the floors/bitizens that I've received "replacement" (i.e., swapping a level 9 for a level 9) bux for, and I've noticed that once I get a bitizen that does not give me a bonus bux, I will never get any more bux out of that level.

Answer (score 0):

Once you fill a spot with a nine, that spot is done.  But if you evict the bitizen on the top spot, everyone moves up one and you get a new spot on the bottom where you can start low and earn bux working your way back up again.  At least that's what I found on Windows phone.

Comment: Weird thing is that I had a filled floor of 9s and I swap with a level 4 and got a BUX but switch to another person and got none

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this new process was "grandfathered" in — so from the point they implemented the new policy, the system would "write down" what your shop's skill levels were *only* when you first swapped in a new employee. Since (with that initial swap) it wouldn't know what their skill levels had been, you could still get away with one lower-level swap and still get bux. But from that point forward, the game would remember what the current skill levels are, and would only give bus if you improved skills with a new employee.

Strategically, if your goal is to get bux, your best bet is to keep at least one employee with as  *low* a skill level as possible (but who still has that shop as their dream job). That way, whenever you get a new employee with that shop as their dream job (who will likely have a skill level higher than your low-level worker), you can "unemploy" the low-skill worker (but do *not* eject them), employ the new worker, and get your bux. Then, you can eject the new worker (or a different one, if you'd rather free up a space on one of the other residential levels) and reemploy the low-level worker. No, you won't get any bux for rehiring the original worker, but you'll be prepared for the next time.

This will, of course, increase your reorder times for the floor, since your overall shop skills level is lower than it could be. But that's all a question of what your priorities are.

Hope this helps — it's been working for me!